# Ajax toolkit is not working on server for framework 4.0 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-ajax

There is a problem in Ajax toolkit,i develop a project in asp.net with framework 4.0,and in it i am using some Ajax controls,when i run my project on local host all Ajax controls works fine but when i  create a virtual directory for this project in the server,Ajax tools not working.In that same server Ajax tools working excellent for framework 3.5 but not works for framework 4.0,So the question that Ajax tools in that server is installed doesn't arise at all,so please tell  me what can i do to run Ajax tools for framework 4.0 on server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for that, I just put these lines of code in my web.config and ajax problem solved.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules>
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFact ory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFact ory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Put that code inside your web.config and your problem will be solved. It works fine for me.

Comment: @Rahul  i am facing same problem. i tried this code  but not work for me. any suggestion ?

Comment: @Rahul, Im facing a similar issue now. Can you please tell me where to add the above lines of code in web.config ?